# How to create a Calendar in Php?

Tags: php, calendar

How can I create a calendar in PHP?

Today should be in bold. How could it be coded?

Comment: This is Too Broad, will lead to very different opinion-based answers, and is a spam seed question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try  [dhtml Calendar](http://www.dynarch.com/projects/calendar/), or maybe [Yahoo UI's Calendar](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/calendar/).

Comment: Sure it is !!  If you want to build really cool UI without too much overhead, Yahoo UI is your friend ! ;)

Answer (score 1):

[PHP: date](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) should give you everything you need.

Then, format everything in a [table](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_tables.asp).

Comment: Sorry, but you're going to have to be more specific in your needs if you want specific help. Otherwise it's just another `plzsendtehcodez` question.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, start by capturing your requirements (should it handle month browsing, should it show a week at a time, etc.) - this should let you derive a functional spec of sorts, which should guide you when actually writing the component/page/application

Comment: no i dont want the shikimiki things it should just print the actual month and today should be in bold

Answer (score 0):

If you mean: "how to show a date picker on your web page from PHP", the answer is to use some default JavaScript library for it. E.g. Dojo or jQuery.